# limited download speed from FTP via WinSCP

Tags: windows, ftp, download, winscp

I have a dedicated server and when trying to backup website sources via WinSCP I have limited download speed to 40 kb/s

This strange thing appears on two machines - Core i5/Win8 and Core i7/Win7
But on Intel Atom/Win8 - I have maximum speed - 300-400 kb/s

What should be changed to get the maximum speed on first two machines?